# Removing duplicates given row's value VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with thousands of rows and in column B there are numerous duplicates and then in column G there is that row's respective value. I need to remove the duplicates from column B, but leave in the row that has the highest value (i.e max column G). Is there a way to automate this via VBA as it'll need to be done on numerous occasions?

Thanks

Comment: Record a macro: sort the data based on column G, then use the remove duplicates. The remove duplicates function will leave the highest value only, if you sort correctly.

Comment: Sort Descending on column G.  Then highlight the entire data set and go to Data > Remove Duplicates.  Choose only column B. It will remove all the duplicates in column B leaving the highest value for each in column G

Comment: @vacip beat me by 6 seconds

Comment: @ScottCraner You are more thorough though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change the name of your sheet

With ws

i = 1 ' Start at Row 1

 Do While Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 2))

j = 1 ' Start at Row 1
    Do While Not IsEmpty(.Cells(j, 2))

    If i <> j Then

        If .Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(j, 2).Value Then

                If .Cells(i, 7).Value > Cells(j, 7) Then

                    Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete
                    j = j - 1
                Else
                    Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                    If i > 1 Then i = i - 1
                    j = 1
                End If
        End If

    End If

    j = j + 1
    Loop

i = i + 1
Loop

End With

End Sub
```